# Regex for SWIFT BIC

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex to validate Swift BIC:

```
^[A-Z]{6}[A-Z0-9]{2}([A-Z0-9]{3})?
```

But this string is correct:

```
AABSDE31X-X
```

How would be the regex to match the entire optional part `([A-Z0-9]{3})?` if present?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the rules here? Any 3 alphanumeric + `-` after the 6 letters and 2 alphanumeric? Try [`^[A-Z]{6}[A-Z0-9]{2}(?:[-A-Z0-9]{3})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/dFKiWe/2).

Comment: @Wiktor your expression returns true for invalid code:
`var code = "AABSDE31X-X"; /^[A-Z]{6}[A-Z0-9]{2}(?:[-A-Z0-9]{3})?$/.test(code)`
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9362

Comment: @KillzoneKid Then it is another dupe that have been so many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you just have to append you regex with $ to terminate it :

```
^[A-Z]{6}[A-Z0-9]{2}([A-Z0-9]{3})?$
```

A great tool to check your regex here :
https://regex101.com/

Hope this helps!